# How to make Termux obtain root access?

Tags: root-access, termux

I am using a rooted Samsung S8+. But, Termux cannot gain root access. I tried `su`, `sudo` unsuccessfully.

When I  tried installing termux-sudo, I had the error `cat: sudo: no such a file or directory`.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Comment: Are you Magisk or SuperSU?

Comment: There is no sudo on Android, only /sbin/su binary exists on rooted phones. How did you root your phone? What does 'ls /sbin' command show? Did you grant root access to Termux app through Magisk or SuperSU app? Do you have SELinux enforcing or permissive? You may edit your question to add further details. Termux-sudo package isn't necessarily needed to run as root, that just a bash wrapper around su binary.

Comment: Can you please show the output of `which su`?

Comment: Instead of sudo ..Try running tsu

Comment: I don't think tsu comes inbuilt with Termux. Requires installation. You should mention that.

Comment: Yes, you need to type "pkg install tsu", and then "tsu" is exactly the same than "sudo" on the PC.

Answer (score 6):

First, install the needed packages.

```
pkg install proot proot-distro tsu fakeroot parted
```

Then, go to a new screen in the terminal and type

```
proot -0 login
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that's the correct order of those commands? I have a strong feeling that it should have been `sudo cat` instead of `cat sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably need to use su rather than sudo. Where did you copy the sudo from? It looks like some incompatible executable, maybe copied from an x64 distro (guessing).

Second, Termux overrides $PATH. You will need to provide full path or to make su available on $PATH. You might want a symlink (ln -s) of su (which might be located in /sbin/, /system/xbin or so).

Comment: This is exactly right, although in my case the symlink was located in xsu. Also, after obtaining su, you need to re overwrite PATH so termux can access all of it's packages again.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed incompatible software. In your output, the line "Exec: exec format error" is the program loader complaining about an incompatible binary format.

Your experiment failed because of wrong software type.