# I can not get access to /proc/sys/kernel/hostname file

Tags: permissions, termux, file-permissions

After following the [Anon Uimik's](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/230582/131553) instructions to get root access here:

[How to make Termux obtain root access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205164/how-to-make-termux-obtain-root-access)

I'm trying to get the value of the file `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` but I'm getting `Permission denied`. Any help?

```
~ # cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
cat: /proc/sys/kernel/hostname: Permission denied
```

Comment: `proot` is pseudo (fake) root. It won't give you root privileges in real environment.